How to make a calculated column of two tables
I'm a bit new to PowerBI. I need help creating a calculated column of two related tables, practically doing multiplication with data found in Table 2 (Tarifa) according to the value in Table 1(Foglio3). but is depend of the person (AGENTE), because to each person the multiply change
I have been trying, but I got an error:

it is not possible to determine a single value for column 'PREZZO_RICORRENTE' in the 'Tarifa' table, this can occur when a measure's formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation. i will refresh the post too with a screenshot of the relations diagram

Thanks

Can you please translate this error to English, or better, swith to English and than copy-paste error message here

it is not possible to determine a single value for column 'PREZZO_RICORRENTE' in the 'Tarifa' table, this can occur when a measure's formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation. i will refresh the post too with a screenshot of the relations diagram

Assuming PREZZO_RICORRENTE is a measure, could you please post the code for that measure too?

prezzo ricorrente, is a decimal numerical data, which comes to be multiplied by the quantity according to the filter (this already does ) then I want to multiply the total amount of a field of the Foglio3 table, by prezzo_ricorrente of the table (tarifa) but it depends on the relationship, the multiplication will be different according to the code. And to explain better I am making the total commissions to be paid for each amount but that will depend on the people ID_AG because each person gets their commission

In which table do you want to create a calculated column? AGENTE?

in table Foglio3, want to make a calculated column, , i want to multiply a column of the   table tarifa with another column of table Foglio3.

Ok. Having link many to one to Agente we can determine a single row in this table releated to current row of Foglio3. But how we can determin a correct row in Tarifa table? there is a link one to many from Agente to Tarifa? We'll have selected several rows in tarifa, which row should we use in formula?
